# How to disable the spaces before the first bar and after the last bar?

Tags: pgfplots, charts

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[adobefonts]{ctex} %支持中文就靠这一行了
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[active,xetex,tightpage]{preview} %这一行有改动，将pdftex换成xetex

\PreviewEnvironment[]{tikzpicture}
\PreviewEnvironment[]{pgfpicture}
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbolsb}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbolsb}{bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathcal}{symbolsb}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\YaHei{\fontspec{微软雅黑}}

%
% Define bar chart colors
%
\definecolor{bblue}{HTML}{4F81BD}
\definecolor{rred}{HTML}{C0504D}
\definecolor{ggreen}{HTML}{9BBB59}
\definecolor{ppurple}{HTML}{9F4C7C}

\pgfplotsset
{
    tick label style = {font=\YaHei\bfseries},
    xticklabel style = {font=\YaHei\bfseries},
    legend style     = {font=\YaHei\bfseries,,cells={anchor=west}},
}

\begin{document}

% ybar控制同一组内bar之间的微小间隔
% ymin控制Y轴的最小数字，ymax控制Y轴的最大数字
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        major x tick style = transparent,
        enlarge x limits = false,
        width  = 0.85*\textwidth,
        height = 8cm,        
        ybar   = 5*\pgflinewidth,
        bar width   = 24pt,
        ymajorgrids = true,
        title  = {\YaHei\bfseries 苹果手机销售情况},
        ymin   = 0,
        ymax   = 100,
        xtick  = data,      
        symbolic x coords = {2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012},
        scaled y ticks    = false,
        enlarge x limits  = 0.25,        
        legend cell align = left,
        legend pos = outer north east,
        nodes near coords,% 在柱子顶部显示实际数字
        tick align = outside,
        bar shift = 0pt,
    ]
        \legend{亿元}
        \addplot[style={bblue,fill=bblue,mark=none}]
            coordinates {(2006, 10)(2007, 60)(2008, 70)(2009, 88)(2010, 44)(2011, 47)(2012, 54)};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result seems ugly. The screenshot is below:

[image]

How to disable the sapces before the first bar and after the last bar?

Comment: Your value for `enlarge x limits=0.25` is too large. Use `0.1` instead, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option value to `enlarge x limits` determines the extra space left and right of the data boundaries. The OP used `0.25` which is too large for his request, so `0.1` reduces this to a somewhat nice amount.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[adobefonts]{ctex} %支持中文就靠这一行了
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[active,xetex,tightpage]{preview} %这一行有改动，将pdftex换成xetex

\PreviewEnvironment[]{tikzpicture}
\PreviewEnvironment[]{pgfpicture}
%\DeclareSymbolFont{symbolsb}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
%\SetSymbolFont{symbolsb}{bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}
%\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathcal}{symbolsb}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\YaHei{}%\fontspec{微软雅黑}}

%
% Define bar chart colors
%
\definecolor{bblue}{HTML}{4F81BD}
\definecolor{rred}{HTML}{C0504D}
\definecolor{ggreen}{HTML}{9BBB59}
\definecolor{ppurple}{HTML}{9F4C7C}

\pgfplotsset
{
    tick label style = {font=\YaHei\bfseries},
    xticklabel style = {font=\YaHei\bfseries},
    legend style     = {font=\YaHei\bfseries,,cells={anchor=west}},
}

\begin{document}

% ybar控制同一组内bar之间的微小间隔
% ymin控制Y轴的最小数字，ymax控制Y轴的最大数字
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        major x tick style = transparent,
        enlarge x limits = false,
        width  = 0.85*\textwidth,
        height = 8cm,        
        ybar   = 5*\pgflinewidth,
        bar width   = 24pt,
        ymajorgrids = true,
        title  = {\YaHei\bfseries 苹果手机销售情况},
        ymin   = 0,
        ymax   = 100,
        xtick  = data,      
        symbolic x coords = {2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012},
        scaled y ticks    = false,
        scale only axis,
        enlarge x limits  = 0.1,        
        legend cell align = left,
        legend pos = outer north east,
        nodes near coords,% 在柱子顶部显示实际数字
        tick align = outside,
        bar shift = 0pt,
    ]
        \legend{亿元}
        \addplot[style={bblue,fill=bblue,mark=none}]
            coordinates {(2006, 10)(2007, 60)(2008, 70)(2009, 88)(2010, 44)(2011, 47)(2012, 54)};
          \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had to disable the Asian fonts related commands since I don't have those fonts installed